# What is the difference between debot fetch and debot start?

Tags: solidity, everscale

I have few different options in the command line: fetch and start. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here https://github.com/tonlabs/tonos-cli/pull/162 Free TON guys says that
"added debot start command as synonym for fetch command."

BUT here https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-SDK/blob/master/docs/mod_debot.md#start thay say

**start** - Starts the DeBot.

Downloads debot smart contract from blockchain and switches it to context zero.

This function must be used by Debot Browser to start a dialog with debot. While the function is executing, several Browser Callbacks can be called, since the debot tries to display all actions from the context 0 to the user.

When the debot starts SDK registers BrowserCallbacks AppObject. Therefore when debote.remove is called the debot is being deleted and the callback is called with finish=true which indicates that it will never be used again.

```
type ParamsOfStart = {
    debot_handle: DebotHandle
}

function start(
    params: ParamsOfStart,
): Promise<void>;
```

and below https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-SDK/blob/master/docs/mod_debot.md#fetch

**fetch** - Fetches DeBot metadata from blockchain.

Downloads DeBot from blockchain and creates and fetches its metadata.

```
type ParamsOfFetch = {
    address: string
}

type ResultOfFetch = {
    info: DebotInfo
}

function fetch(
    params: ParamsOfFetch,
): Promise<ResultOfFetch>;
```

here in tg chat https://t.me/freeton_dev_exp You can find SDK developers